# pH of solution after adding SiCl4

Tags: acid-base

Why is it that adding $\ce{SiCl4}$ will cause the pH of a solution to become acidic? I thought that only salts (ionic bonds break in water) can change the pH once dissolved in water. $\ce{SiCl4}$ has covalent bonds, so why does the pH change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silicon is very oxophilic and $\ce{SiCl4}$ irreversibly hydrolyzes in water as follows:
$$\ce{SiCl4_{(l)} + 4 H2O_{(l)} -> 4 HCl_{(aq)} + Si(OH)4_{(s)}} $$

The release of $\ce{HCl}$ creates hydrochloric acid and lowers the pH.

Comment: I wonder if the reaction in water would be: $$\ce{SiCl4 + 2 H2O -> 4 HCl + SiO_{2(s)}} $$

Comment: Depends on concentration I think

Comment: $\ce{Si(OH)4}$ will reversibly dehydrate and coagulate to some extend forming a sol over time. But when you use aqueous processes to form $\ce{SiO2}$ you get a substantial amount of $\ce{Si(OH)4}$  first.

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{Si(OH)4}$ exists as $\ce{SiO2.2H2O}$ called Silica Gel. $\ce{Si(OH)4}$ as such does not stand for long, probably due to overcrowding of electrons around Si atom by $\ce{4 OH-}$ groups. Hence, $\ce{Si(OH)4}$ stabilises itself as $\ce{SiO2.2H2O}$